# Handling android onclick for multiple buttons (81 total)

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

I'm currently creating an Ultimate Tic Tac Toe app which consists of 81 buttons. The way I handled it when it was regular tic tac toe was to make a switch statement for 9 buttons. I'm just wondering if creating a switch for all 81 buttons is still the best way to handle all the button presses?

[image: Ultimate Tic Tac Toe]

Comment: You could use a `tag` on the view to put information in.

Comment: Do you generate elements using pure codes or inflate a samle xml layout for all?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I created this making an xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all elements set onClick **with a same name**:

```
<LinearLayout
//blah blah
android:onClick="myClickFunction"
/>
```

and then in your Java file you will need **only this one click Listener**:

```
   public void myClickFunction(View v) {
            String mytag=(String) v.getTag();
            // And do something with tag or id
       }
```

Comment: Because a same name of `android:onClick` is set for all of them.

Comment: I get `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.thatboytitz.ultimatetictactoe, PID: 16320
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method MyClickFunction(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button01'`

Comment: Sorry. The listener method should be defined as a simple method not a clickListener. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the [`OnClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) event you have the view.

Work with it directly

Comment: But within the Onclick do I do: 
    `public void OnClick(View view) {`
         `switch(view.getId()){`
for all 81 buttons?

Comment: You can create a custom view and store it's position while creating it. Then cast the view inside the onclick to get the apropriates coordinate. you can also set a tag to the view.

Comment: I'm confused on what you're talking about. How would you do that?

Comment: Take a look at [Creating Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).